# What's the method for finding train connections?

Tags: gtfs

I have looked at the data examples for GTFS. I want to be able to find a method or logic to finding train connections.

For example. We have three train station:
Big_City_Station (which is a huge destination)
Mid-size_Station (a large hub - transfer point)
Midway_Station (a hub 20 miles from Big_City_Station - transfer point)
Home_Station (A suburb where the trips begin each morning)

There are several train routes which leave from Home_Station. Let's call them primary and secondary. Primary and Secondary almost always stop at the Midway_Station. In order to get to the Big_City_Station we start at Home_Station and transfer to make the connection at Midway_Station to hopefully catch a train to Big_City_Station.

What is the method to make the transfer points be the most efficient? Is there an algorithms for getting from point A to B including the transfer stations? Or is the programming solution simply only this:
Check Home_Station for next train that stops at a transfer point and get the train times to make connections, if there isn't a train trip available without stops from Home_Station to Big_City_Station? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pathfinding (routing, trip planning, ...) algorithms on graphs with time restrictions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245840/pathfinding-routing-trip-planning-algorithms-on-graphs-with-time-restric)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use an existing transit routing engine (https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/wiki or http://graphserver.github.io/graphserver/), for example.

There have also been some papers on determining the transfer patterns in a transit network.  You might check out Fast Routing in
Very Large Public Transportation Networks
using Transfer Patterns: http://ad.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/files/transferpatterns.pdf