# what is the fastest way of a typical 2d array path finding?

Tags: performance, algorithm, python-3.x

an expecting result is like this one.

```
0 0 0 1 0 * * * 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 * 1 * * 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 * 1 0 * 0 0 0
0 * * 0 1 * 1 0 * 0 0 0
0 * 1 1 1 * 1 0 * * 0 0
0 * 0 1 1 * 1 0 0 * 0 0
0 * 0 0 1 * 1 0 0 * 0 0
0 * * * * * 1 0 0 * * 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 * 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 * 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 * 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 * *
```

you can only walk at 4 directions,no 45 degree direction, im using A* , i changed part of the original algorithm for more suited in my case.

here's my python code:

i run it 1000 times.

the cost is 1.4s~1.5s

```
def astar(m,startp,endp):
    w,h = 12,12
    sx,sy = startp
    ex,ey = endp
    #[parent node, x, y,g,f]
    node = [None,sx,sy,0,abs(ex-sx)+abs(ey-sy)] 
    closeList = [node]
    createdList = {}
    createdList[sy*w+sx] = node
    k=0
    while(closeList):
        node = closeList.pop(0)
        x = node[1]
        y = node[2]
        l = node[3]+1
        k+=1
        #find neighbours 
        #make the path not too strange
        if k&1:
            neighbours = ((x,y+1),(x,y-1),(x+1,y),(x-1,y))
        else:
            neighbours = ((x+1,y),(x-1,y),(x,y+1),(x,y-1))
        for nx,ny in neighbours:
            if nx==ex and ny==ey:
                path = [(ex,ey)]
                while node:
                    path.append((node[1],node[2]))
                    node = node[0]
                return list(reversed(path))            
            if 0<=nx<w and 0<=ny<h and m[ny][nx]==0:
                if ny*w+nx not in createdList:
                    nn = (node,nx,ny,l,l+abs(nx-ex)+abs(ny-ey))
                    createdList[ny*w+nx] = nn
                    #adding to closelist ,using binary heap
                    nni = len(closeList)
                    closeList.append(nn)
                    while nni:
                        i = (nni-1)>>1
                        if closeList[i][4]>nn[4]:
                            closeList[i],closeList[nni] = nn,closeList[i]
                            nni = i
                        else:
                            break


    return 'not found'

m = ((0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
     (0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
     (0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
     (0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
     (0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
     (0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
     (0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
     (0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
     (0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
     (0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
     (0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
     (0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
     )

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    result = astar(m,(2,3),(11,11))
print(time.time()-t1) 
cm = [list(x[:]) for x in m]


if isinstance(result, list):
    for y in range(len(m)):
        my = m[y]
        for x in range(len(my)):
            for px,py in result:
                if px==x and py ==y:
                    cm[y][x] = '*'

for my in cm:
    print(' '.join([str(x) for x in my]))

exit(0)
```

tell me if you know faster or fastest way by now.

Comment: Not an answer, but something you may want to compare your performance with: http://networkx.lanl.gov/ implementation of shortest paths.

Answer (score 1):

A* algorithm is pretty fast one for a known graph (all edges are known and you can estimate distance to the target using some admissible heuristic).

There are some improvements to A* algorithm which makes it faster at the cost of being *less optimal*. The most common is [A*-Epsilon (AKA bounded A*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Bounded_relaxation). The idea is to allow the algorithm to develop nodes that are `(1+epsilon)*MIN` (where regular A* develops only MIN). The result (depending on the epsilon value of course) is usually a faster solution, but the path found is at most `(1+epsilon) * OPTIMAL`.

---

Another possible optimization is doing A* from one end - and from the other (the "exit") do a BFS simultaneously. This technique is called **[bi-directional search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search)** - and is usually a great way to improve performance in unweighted graphs when the problem has a single final state. I tried to explain the principles of bi-directional search once in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7220232/572670)